# is MvxBindableListAdapter deprecated in v3?

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to compile cheesebaron.HorizontalListView with MvvmCross support, but the class BindableHorizontalListView is not compiled due to MvxBindableListAdapter type not found.
What is its replacement in v3 ?
Thanks for help

Comment: Has I currently don't have access to the PC, I'm not sure of I'm about to say, but I believe that in general the prefix 'bindable' has been deprecated. So... Maybe in this case, the class is now called 'MvxListAdapter'.

Comment: No, this is not the case - I've checked all the code, and there are no any *ListAdapter. I will try to use MvxAdapter and change the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - many names were shortened and many namespaces flattened as part of the changes for v3

`MvxBindableListAdapter` became `MvxAdapter` - much easier to remember (IMO)

Some of these changes were introduced in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/hot-tuna-mvvmcross-v3-progress.html - including the slide deck at: https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/mvvmcross-hot-tuna